# Is there any kind of shouldComponentRender in React

Tags: reactjs

Consider that there's a tabbed accordion, user can open one tab at a time, rendering each container take more than 100 milliseconds (sometimes like 1 second). How could I implement such a thing that user don't feel lag every time navigating between tabs and first time rendering won't be slow as well?

I'm thinking of these ways to do that:

1. Detaching element (or caching)
2. Implementing something like shouldComponentUpdate but for first time render
3. Some middle-way component that won't render if tab is hidden in first render and won't update if currently rendered tab is hidden.
4. Check if tab is rendered before and don't add it if it's not active and not rendered

Is there any library or Component that do such a thing? Or how can I implement one of these?

P.S: That's not only about performance, there's scroll position, user interactions that needs to be preserved when switching between tabs (like an input that is changed in one)

Comment: If you don't want your component to render, return `null` from its `render` method. But I would venture that you have bigger fish to fry if each tab is taking 100–1,000ms to render.

Comment: @Jordan The real problem isn't about time and perfs, when I render all of them at once it may take that much of time, if I return null for some then in each switch I must render tabs that once was rendered, and user will feel it.

Comment: Can you put your code in a snippet or jsfiddle?

Comment: I'm trying to create a snippet but can't find any snippet site that support jsx and react 0.14!

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/reactjs/69z2wepo/

Comment: https://gist.github.com/kt0/d1d8f41b6e44022087e7 and https://jsbin.com/qaholeraqi/edit?html,js,output  not very optimized btw!

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/drctma1u/